# How to persist checked items across pagination requests in Laravel?

Tags: php, forms, pagination, laravel

I have a form where I show some items, which can be selected by the user.
There are over 1000 items so I'm using pagination.

What would be the best way to persist the checked items, when user go to the next page?

To store all these items in hidden fields wouldn't be an option, because they are to much items.

My View:

```
@foreach($articles['uncommitted'] as $article)
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="articles[]"></td>
        <td>{{{$article->articlename}}}</td>
        <td>{{{$article->category->catname}}}</td>
        <td>{{{strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M', strtotime($article->created_at))}}
        <td>{{{$article->rrp}}}</td>>created_at))}}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
{{$links}}
```

This form will be paginated.

Comment: Store them in database

Comment: I would definitively use the Session for that. For each request I would _flash_ the id of selected items. See: http://laravel.com/docs/session#flash-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you are facing two problems: persisting the checked items across pagination request, and retrieving the checked items back to the view.

To persist the checked items across pagination request, I would [*flash*](http://laravel.com/docs/session#flash-data) the checked items into the Session. The controller method will look something as follows.

```
public function fill_form()
{
    $items = Item::paginate(25);

    // Retrieve checked items in session.
    $checked_items = []
    if (Session::has('checked_items'))
        $checked_items = Session::get('checked_items');

    // Persist new checked items.
    $checked_items = array_merge($checked_items, Input::get('item'));
    Session::flash('checked_items', $checked_items);

    return View::make('form')
        ->with('items', $items);
}
```

As you can see the *checked items* will be available in the session within pagination requests.

Now for the case to display the checked items back to the view I would send the *checked items* in session to the view via [old input](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#old-input). That said, the return value would be changed as follows.

```
public function fill_form()
{
    # code intentionally omitted #

    return View::make('form')
        ->with('items', $items)
        ->withInput($checked_items);
}
```

Then in your views the checked items will persist their checked value. Obviously, you should [use Laravel to generate your checkboxes](http://laravel.com/docs/html#checkboxes-and-radio-buttons).

---

**How to get all item (checked or not) on submit?**

Maybe, if you are render items with checkboxes you will need to know which of those checkboxes were checked and which not when paginating. A simply solution will be adding an extra input hidden field for each checkbox with a default value, it will look as follows:

```
{{ Form::hidden('item1', 'off') }}
{{ Form::checkbox('item1', 'on') }}

{{ Form::hidden('item2', 'off') }}
{{ Form::checkbox('item2', 'on') }}

{{ Form::hidden('item3', 'off') }}
{{ Form::checkbox('item3', 'on') }}
```

After submitting the form, when paginating, for checked item you will receive the expected value, for those not checked you will receive the hidden value.

**Note 1**, it is important to put the hidden input **before** each checkbox.
**Note 2**, each hidden input should have the same name as the checkbox.

Comment: It is part for my solution, but how I know user clicked a checkbox?
The form will be send if user have selected all his prefered items.

Comment: @MarcoMartens to do this you should use an extra hidden field **before** each checkbox with a default value that will indicate which items were not checked. I will explain it more in my answer.

Comment: So clever and easy. Thanks a lot.

Only one question: Is this good practice? Or is there any cleaner solution?

If there is no better solution, i will use this way.

Comment: A friend of mine told me that he will use Cookies... but I prefer this solution. The use of hidden input it is widely in ASP.NET Web Forms and I think ASP.NET MVC do the same too. So I think it could be a good or at least a common practice.

Comment: Little change:

This solution is not working with pagination, because the checkbox state is lost when paginate. 

So I use this solution and js.
If chechbox state is change, I set the hidden field of this item to on.

Comment: @MarcoMartens, your pagination link will do GET requests, you should force those links to a POST request instead. Doing this, you will have the state of your checkboxes.

Comment: Yes, but for this I must rewrite the pagination class from laravel. 
So I use ajax to set a session, this works good for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood your question, I think what you're looking for is caching: http://four.laravel.com/docs/cache

Here's an excerpt from the docs:

---

**Database Cache**

When using the database cache driver, you will need to setup a table to contain the cache items. Below is an example Schema declaration for the table:

```
Schema::create('cache', function($table)
{
    $table->string('key')->unique();
    $table->text('value');
    $table->integer('expiration');
});
```

---

If you're wanting to store form data across requests, then you'll want to use Session - excerpt from the docs (http://four.laravel.com/docs/session):

**Database Sessions**

When using the database session driver, you will need to setup a table to contain the session items. Below is an example Schema declaration for the table:

```
Schema::create('sessions', function($table)
{
    $table->string('id')->unique();
    $table->text('payload');
    $table->integer('last_activity');
});
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood me.

I have a form where the user can select items. These items will be stored in a list (of these items).

So the form use checkboxes. The user select some items and if he go on next page, the selected items are disabled, because of the reload.

I am searching for a way to save these items temporary.

A way would be to show all items on one page, but this wouldn't be good practice.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend using Session: http://four.laravel.com/docs/session You can even use a database session driver. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Of course, but how can I get the values of checkboxes? The user submit the form after he has selected all his prefered items.

Comment: Maybe it would help me understand your issue better if you added some source code. Are your checkboxes dynamically generated? What are your field names? ...etc

Comment: Yes the checkboxes are dynamically generated.
The fieldname of all checkboxes is the same, because i used it as an array.

Comment: @MarcoMartens Can you add some source code to your question? Show me what your checkbox loop looks like and the HTML that it generates.

Comment: Yes I added my html in the top.